# How to get color family values for product in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to get `color family values`  and `option Id` for product in magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Inject an instance of `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` to your constructor, before you use that to get an entity's attribute option values.

```
protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig)
{
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}

public function getAttributeOptionValues()
{
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', '<your_attribute_code_here>');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    foreach ($options as $optionId => $optionValue) {
        /* Your logic here; */
    }
}
```

Replace `your_attribute_code_here` with the required attribute code ( in your case **color family**).